# Can't enable AudioSource after Unity crashed

Tags: unity-game-engine

Yesterday everything was working perfectly. The build on my android still does. But last night when I was trying to add some new code to read from a json file, Unity crashed. I had to force quit, and when it came back I couldn't see anything that changed however none of my sound effects would play. They all gave me the "Can not play disabled audio source" error. I thought something must have changed that I can't pinpoint, but no matter what I tried I couldn't get them to play again.

So I started a whole new project with just 1 audio source prefab, 1 game object in the hierarchy, and 1 simple play script to test. The script is attached to the game object and I passed the audio source prefab to the inspector variable. And it still gives me the error. When I Debug.Log the isActiveAndEnabled property is false. Enabled was false too so I tried to manually force it to true, but no change. I feel like something really messed up in Unity during the crash and I don't know how to fix it. I see other questions with this error but they are all either missing a basic checkbox or destroying the object, neither of which I'm doing. I don't know how to debug further than this. The audio clip plays fine in the preview. I appreciate any guidance. This is all my code is right now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class testSound : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource abc;

    void Start()
    {
        abc.enabled = true;
        Debug.Log("abc is active/enabled: " + abc.isActiveAndEnabled);
        Debug.Log("abc enabled: " + abc.enabled);
        Debug.Log("abc tag: " + abc.tag);
        abc.Play();
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is Ding? It’s clearly not the audio source on your object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issues in your code as you only need the component and .Play() function. Logically, the issue should be somewhere so here are some tips that may help you:

- Check during play time if the GameObject that have the AudioSource component is still active/not destroyed, since your "isActiveAndEnabled()" returns false, the problem is probably there.
- Try to put the AudioSource component in the same GameObject as the script, this way you ensure that both are either enabled or disabled.
- Uncheck the "Play on Awake" and try again, since your code is already doing the work of .Play()

Also, I don't know if you tried but the "Play on Awake" option should work 100% of the time without any code. So normaly you should hear the sound at the beginning of your gmae or when the object is enabled.

Hopefully it will guide you the solution.

Comment: Thank you! I played around with your suggestions and I think it is something to do with #1. Putting the audio source component directly on the GameObject with the script plays fine. Also I discovered if I have the AudioSource as an object in my hierarchy, I can drag that to my GameObject's script inspector and it also plays. However if I create a PREFAB out of that AudioSource and drag that into the object's script inspector (what I was doing before), I get the error. It seems to really not like the audio source as a prefab. Not ideal for what I imagined, but I can work with this.

Comment: Yeah, I had lot of problems between my prefabs and code aswell. If you really need to use prefabs and play sound on start, then you will need to enable and link the object inside of your code instead of the inspector, since the object won't exist (yet).
Anyway, good thing you found out the problem.